# A mean in which values are weighted by themselves

Tags: average, means, descriptive-statistics

I'm looking for the name of the following expression:

$$
\frac{\sum_{i} x_i^2}{\sum_i x_i}
$$

This can be understood as a type of average in which each value is weighted by itself – in other words, a type of average in which near-zero values are ignored. Here are some examples:

- $[0, 0, 100, 0, 100] \rightarrow 100$
- $[10, 10, 10, 10, 10] \rightarrow 10$
- $[1000, 100, 0, 0, 0] \rightarrow 918.18$

Does this type of mean have a name? What are some typical use cases?

Comment: I should note that all values are assumed non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Weighted aM is given as $$\bar x=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i}$$
In your case it a particular weighted AM,  where the frequency of the variables $x_i$ is $x_i$ itself: $f_i=x_i.$

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying :) – is there a name for this particular self-weighted setup, or are you aware of a particular use case for it I can refer to?

Comment: No there is no special name given to this one. It is a mean which will lie metween the max of $x_i$ and the min of $x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the expression

$$
\frac{x^n}{\sum_i x_i^n}
$$

as a polynomial approximation of the softmax weighting

$$
\frac{e^{x/T}}{\sum_i e^{x_i/T}}.
$$

One difference is that $e^0 = 1$ while $0^n = 0$. The other is that the
exponential grows much faster, especially when $T$ is small; similarly, larger $n$ will
increase the bias towards the maximum and away from the average.

We can therefore frame the expression given in the question as a polynomial
approximation of a softmax-weighted mean with $n=1$:

$$
\sum_j \frac{x_j^1}{\sum_i x_i^1} x_j
$$

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27643810), you could call it a "self-weighted mean", and for a set of positive values it should actually lie between the arithmetic mean and the maximum.